# How to write a query on mysql which will calculate how many days in a row by this time the user visited the application

Tags: mysql, sql, join, row, union

I have table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Activity (LoginDate DATE, ID int);                             

INSERT INTO Activity VALUES
    ("2016-10-01", 2), ("2016-10-01", 1), ("2016-10-02", 1), ("2016-10-02", 3), 
    ("2016-10-03", 1), ("2016-10-03", 3), ("2016-10-04", 2), ("2016-10-05", 1);
```

and need to recieve something like this:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGwVp.png)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Date</th><th>UserID</th><th>Days in Row</th></tr><tr><td>2016-10-01</td><td>2</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>2016-10-01</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>2016-10-02</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2016-10-02</td><td>3</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>2016-10-03</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>2016-10-03</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2016-10-04</td><td>2</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>2016-10-05</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

by using only sql or t-sql, without CTE. Any ideas?

Comment: Upload your images *here*.  Don't use some other website.  I'm not clicking that link.  (Or better yet, don't use images at all - copy/paste the results you're wanting in the body of the question and format it.  If you need a good table formatter, you can use this: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: Thank you, got it

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, you have to specify the column you'd like to insert the values into in your INSERT INTO statement. See how to use this statement here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: I need an arbitrary column that will automatically count how many days in row the user has logged in,  based on the data that available in the table

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MySQL, so take this more as just pseudo code. Could something like this work for you?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TrackConsecutiveVisits()
     BEGIN

     CREATE TABLE Activity_Results (LoginDate DATE, ID int, con_visits int);

     DECLARE con_visit INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

     DECLARE last_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE last_date DATE DEFAULT "1900-01-01";
     DECLARE cur_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE cur_date DATE DEFAULT "1900-01-01";

     DECLARE concur CURSOR FOR 
         SELECT ID,
                LoginDate
           FROM Activity
          ORDER
             BY id,
                loginDate;

    OPEN con_cursor;

    con_loop: LOOP
        FETCH concur INTO cur_id, cur_date;

        IF last_id = cur_id AND last_date + 1 = cur_date THEN
            SET con_visit = con_visit + 1
        ELSE
            SET con_visit = 0
        END IF

        INSERT INTO Activity_Results VALUES (cur_id, cur_date, con_visit)

        SET last_id = cur_id;
        SET last_date = cur_date;

    END LOOP

    CLOSE concur

END;
```